# Are BackGround Tasks persistent? (Windows/Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

In order to run a background task for an application I need to register it first while the application is in the foreground (AFAIK).

Can this be done without the application in the foreground?
If yes, after the background task is registered once, does it need to be registered again after the device reboots?

My objective is to run a background task from a geofence notification event.This should be available  after the application has been run once to configure the user settings.

On a related note, are geofences exclusively checked via wireless networks and how would I retrieve the location of the home or work geofences/locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app needs to run in order to register the BackgroundTask initially. Once the task is registered the app doesn't need to re-run. The task will continue automatically after a reboot.

Geofences generally work based on GPS rather than on wireless networks, although if the device doesn't have GPS it'll fall back to less precise methods such as nearby cell towers or wireless networks. The app will need to define its own geofences for home and work. It can't directly query the user's home or work locations or access Cortana's locations database.